# Apache rewriter - Complex rewriter for files without extension

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewrite-module

I need to rewrite all requests to files at mydomain.com/storage/archive/**ab7572d3-c697-4cfa-9b23-71b6f9c388d1**

to

mydomain.com/**public**/storage/archive/**ab7572d3-c697-4cfa-9b23-71b6f9c388d1**

So I am adding "public" in the url, nothing else. The files are stored as shown above: 36 characters without extension. Therefore I am looking for a regex to match **/storage/archive/** followed by 36 character long file name without extension

I am trying to make it through .htaccess file.

Comment: `[a-z0-9-]{36}` matches a 36 characters long combination of (lowercase) letters, digits and a minus "hyphen".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`RewriteRule`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) to match the whole path and prepend your new parent to it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(storage/archive/[0-9a-f-]{36}.*) /public/$1 [R]
```

The [regex itself](https://regex101.com/r/PlzMVF/1) is pretty basic:

- `^` match at the beginning of the path
- `/` match a literal forward slash
- `(…)` capture this parenthesized part as `$1`

  - `storage/archive/` (literal text match)
  - `[0-9a-f-]{36}` match any [digit, letter from `a` to `f`, or a dash] 36 times
  - `.*` plus anything else you see (note, this will *not* include query strings)

(Yes, I could have put that first slash inside the capture, but I wanted it to be clearer when I rebuilt it with `/public`; otherwise, it'd be `/public$1`. Same functionality, but a little less legible.)